# Wrapper method for Task.Factory.StartNew to execute custom methods with different parameters and return values

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, task, cancellation-token

I'm developing an **MDI** application in **C#** with **.NET 4.0**. I created a wrapper class `TaskManager` to manage the execution of some methods on separate Tasks.

So I can call:

```
_taskManager.StartNewTask(MethodName);
```

with every intense work method that I need to execute on a separeted `Task`.

I created this wrapper class to avoid calls to `Task.Factory.StartNew()` scattered all around the code and so keep it clean and also to be able to somehow keep track of threading.

My problem is that now I'm trying to implement the cancellation of `Task`, such as if the user press **ESC key** the `Task` aborts. To do this I need to use the `CancellationToken` and add it as a parameter to all of my methods. It then has to be checked within each method body. For example:

```
private void MethodName(CancellationToken ct)
{
    // Verify cancellation request
    if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        // Log the cancellation request "The task was cancelled before it got started"
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }

    // Do the heavy work here
    // ...
    // At some critic point check again the cancellation request
    if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        // Log the cancellation request "The task was cancelled while still running"
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }
}
```

Now, my `TaskManager.StartNewTask()` logic is this:

```
public int StartNewTask(Action method)
{
    try
    {
        CancellationToken ct = _cts.Token;
        Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(method, ct);

        _tasksCount++;
        _tasksList.Add(task.Id, task);

        return task.Id;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.Error("Cannot execute task.", ex);
    }

    return -1;
}
```

What I'd want:

1. **I need to change the logic of** `TaskManager.StartNewTask()` **to be able to pass the CancellationToken to the method** but I don't know how to do it...
2. I'd also like to know if it is possible to create an even **more generic** `TaskManager.StartNewTask()` method that can execute any kind of method with **any number of input parameters** and also **any kind of return value**.

I need something like this:

```
// I don't know ho to change the method signature to accept
// methods with parameters as parameter...
public int StartNewTask(Action method)
{
    try
    {
        CancellationToken ct = _cts.Token;
        // Here I need to pass the CancellationToken back to the method
        // I know that this can't be the way...
        Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(method(ct), ct);

        _tasksCount++;
        _tasksList.Add(task.Id, task);

        return task.Id;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.Error("Cannot execute task.", ex);
    }

    return -1;
}
```

**UPDATE 1 (for Question n. 2)**
(changed the CustomMethod)

If I have to execute a method like

```
int CustomMethod (int a, int b, CancellationToken ct)
```

within a new `Task` using my `TaskManager.StartNewTask()` method, how should I change `StartNewTask()` and how should I make the call?

Something like

```
int result = taskManager.StartNewTask(CustomMethod(<input parameters here>));
```

The code could be something like this

```
public partial class MyForm : Form
{
    private readonly TaskManager _taskManager;

    public MyForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _taskManager = TaskManager.GetInstance();
    }

    private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // This is the call to StartNewTask()
        // where now I need to set the parameters for CustomMethod()

        // Input parameters could be class variables or a custom object
        // with specific Properties such as:
        // MyObject.MyString, MyObject.MyDouble
        int result = _taskManager.StartNewTask(CustomMethod<input parameters here>);

        // Do something with my result...
        MessageBox.Show("Result: " + result, "Operation", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }

    private int CustomMethod(int a, int b, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }

        int result = -1;

        // Do some heavy work with int 'a', int 'b' and produce result...
        // Meanwhile check again for cancel request

        return a + b;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

After trying @Sriram Sakthivel suggestion for my question 2, I've now this code:

```
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // a=1 and b=3
    int result = _taskManager.StartNewTask((ct) => CustomMethod(1, 3, ct));
    // On the MessageBox I get 2...
    MessageBox.Show("Result: " + result, "Operation", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}

private int CustomMethod(int a, int b, CancellationToken ct)
{
    if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }

    // a=1 and b=3, so the sum must me 4...
    return a + b;
}

public class TaskManager
{
    private static readonly TaskManager Instance = new TaskManager();
    private readonly Dictionary<int, Task> _tasksList;
    private static int _tasksCount;
    private static CancellationTokenSource _cts;

    public int StartNewTask(Action<CancellationToken> method)
    {
        try
        {
            CancellationToken ct = _cts.Token;
            Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => method, ct);

            _tasksCount++;
            _tasksList.Add(task.Id, task);

            return task.Id;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error("Cannot execute the task.", ex);
        }

        return -1;
    }
}
```

It gets me back 2... but a = 1 and b = 3... so the sum should be 4!

It probably has to do with the return type of `TaskManager.StartNewTask()`... But how should I manage the return values of the methods that I execute in new Tasks? What's wrong?

Comment: Look at what you're returning from your `StartNewTask` method? You return the `TaskId` not the computational result. For you to enable returning values you need `Func<CancellationToken, int>` and not `Action<CancellationToken>`.

Comment: Yes, that is right. But now, how do I manage the return of the Task Id and also the return value of the method I'm running?

Comment: Create a new class to store both and return the instance of that, or use output parameters. I suggest first option.

Comment: Reading around ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537613(v=vs.110).aspx)) I found a way to get back results from method running inside a Task by using `Task<type>` (`Task<int>`, etc.). So the call should be like: `Task<int> myTask = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(method, ct)`. Now, if I want to make my `TaskManager.StartNewTask()` more generic and being able to accept any kind of method as parameter and return any kind of value the method returns, how should I proceed? Something like: public Task<genericType> StartNewTask(Func<CancellationToken, genericType> method)...

Answer (score 1):

I guess you simply need `Action<CancellationToken>` unless I misunderstood.

```
public int StartNewTask(Action<CancellationToken> method)
{
    try
    {
        CancellationToken ct = _cts.Token;
        Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(method(ct), ct);

        _tasksCount++;
        _tasksList.Add(task.Id, task);

        return task.Id;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.Error("Cannot execute task.", ex);
    }

    return -1;
}
```

For your question 2: You can use closures to access the surrounding of the method where the anonymous method or lambda is created. Otherwise, how do you plan to pass the n number of arguments? where do you get them from?

You can use closures to workaround this. Jon explains closures [here](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter5/closures.aspx)

```
int result = _taskManager.StartNewTask((ct)=> CustomMethod(paramA, paramB,ct));
```

Comment: Question 1: Yes, it works!

Question 2: can you be more explicit of what you mean with "use clousures to access the surrounding of the method"? Can you add a code example to your answer?

Suppose I want to execute a `int CustomMethod (string a, double b, CancellationToken ct)` method with my `TaskManager.StartNewTask()` method. How should I change my `StartNewTask()` and how should I make the call `int return = taskManager.StartNewTask(CustomMethod(<input parameters here>));`?

Comment: @RainbowCoder I will update my post, but how do you intend to pass the parameters, I have no idea with that. Where will you get those arbitrary parameters from?

Comment: I've updated my answer, see if that helps. Not tested though.

Comment: It works, but I have some strange behaviour... I'll update the code on the question.